# Google Cloud ISO 27001, 27017, 27018 certificates have expired. Where can I get the new ones

Tags: security, certificate, google-cloud-platform, iso

I have a project hosted on **Google Cloud Platform** and as part of a security audit we found out that the certificates issued by EY CertifyPoint to Google for **ISO 27001, ISO 27017 and ISO 27018 compliance have expired** on Apr 14th, 2018.

These certificates are posted on the [Standards, Regulations & Certifications](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/) page. But as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCP_ISO_27001_Fall_2017.pdf), in this case the ISO 27001 has expired. The same is true for the ISO 27017 and ISO 27018 certificates.

Do any of you know **where can I get the new ones** (assuming they have been renewed)?

Comment: I presume you would contact Google. I don't think anyone here can help you.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, I was hoping someone from the GCP team would come by and answer my question, because these forums are the only support I have available for my project.

Comment: This is a community site, not affiliated with Google. You should not expect a response from anyone at Google (though it could possibly happen). If I were you I would report the issue in their [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: :D      @MichaelHampton

Comment: @MichaelHampton The GCP suggests these forums to get in touch with people that work on the platform. I didn't think this was really an issue with the service (it's just the documentation that's missing) so that why I didn't report it in their issue tracker, but thanks for your suggestions =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer I work for Google Cloud Platform Support.

The Engeneering team It is already aware of the issue and it is currently working in order to fix this.

As you can check there as been as well a public comment from the official channels regarding this issue:
https://twitter.com/htafoya/status/986343658365517825

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gallo! I'll be on the lookout for the updated documentation then. Thanks!